# Metal - dispersive media?

Tags: waves, acoustics, dispersion, ultrasound

Can metal alloys be regarded as "dispersive media" if they are excited with ultrasonic waves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't mention so I write it here:

First, it depends on "metal alloys" and ultrasonic frequency and wavelength.

Metal alloys are crystalline material. Heterogeneity, in any form, could appear in this structure. Alloys generally have heterogeneities. If the wavelength of your elastic wave in order of heterogeneities length scale, a dispersive wave can be captured.